# Can I use the structure "possibility for sb. to do"?

Tags: prepositions, infinitives

> *"There is no possibility for him to be accepted to this university."*

Is this sentence grammatically correct or does it sound natural?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not word it like this. I would say, There is no possibility of his being accepted to the University,"  or, "There is no possibility that he will be accepted to the University." You could use the word "chance" in place of "possibility". More informally, I might say, "There's no way he's getting into this University."